# jQuery loop through HTML elements with common class and compare string given with the content

Tags: jquery, html, class, string-comparison

In a jQuery function I need to loop through several HTML elements with the same class and compare a specific string with the content of those elements in each iteration.

Can anyone give me some tips how to do this?

Comment: Not mind readers here..post your code..

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
$.each($('.your-class-name'), function() {
      if($(this).text() == 'your-text')
               console.log('yes');
      else
               console.log('no');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi u can do it through this below code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var foundin = $('.yourclass:contains("I am a simple string")');
});
</script>
```

The foundin will be a jQuery object that contains any matched element. See the API information at: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains#text

Answer (score 1):

here is the **demo [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/EnMeh/1/)** for you, check it out.

HTML :

```
<div class="my_class">This is div 1</div>
<div class="my_class">This is div 2</div>
<div class="my_class">This is div 3</div>
<div class="my_class">This is div 4</div>
```

JS:

```
var search_text = "This is div 4";
// Loop through each item
$('.my_class').each(function(index) {
    var current_elem_text = $(this).html();
    alert(current_elem_text);

    if(current_elem_text == search_text)
    {
        alert('Hey ! it matches ');
    }
    else
    {
         alert('Sorry it does not match ');   
    }

});
```

Comment: If my code helped you then please consider accepting the answer. By accepting someone's answer you appreciate the effort one has put in resolving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the .each() function. Check out the official documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/each/

> The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise
>   and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements
>   that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is
>   passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly,
>   the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so
>   the keyword this refers to the element.

```
// Loop through each item
$('.yourclass').each(function(index) {
     // Make your comparison
     console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```